# About multiple SPI on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: pi-3, spi

I'm tying to use MCP3008 to read the ADC signal from sensors.

But I need to transfer the data through the LoRa module.

Which is also the SPI interdace. The example of ping pong has been done.

But is that ok to use both SPI interfaces ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect multiple spi devices (ADCs) to Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71448/how-to-connect-multiple-spi-devices-adcs-to-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the devices are on different SPI channels that is okay.

The Pi main SPI device has two channels (spidev0.0 and spidev0.1).

The Pi auxiliary SPI device has three channels (spidev1.0, spidev1.1, and spidev1.2).